# Why doesn't the regex engine backtrack for .*?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, backtracking, nfa

I am trying to understand the following regex:
Having:

```
SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c main.c \  
            missing.c msg.c node.c re.c version.c
```

as a multiline text the following regex fails to match:

```
~$ perl -e '  
my $var = "SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c main.c \  
missing.c msg.c node.c re.c version.c";  
$var =~ /^\w+=(.*(\\\n.*))/;  
print "$1\n";
```

But I am not sure why.
I mean the `.*` will match up till the end of the line (`\n`). Then since the `.` can not match the end of the line the match fails. Then since the `*` is optional shouldn't the regex  engine backtrack and release `\` and try to match again?
This does not seem to happen as the back reference is empty.
Could someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 5):

*Edited to take into account comments by @amon (thank you, by the way)*

Your assignment statement...

```
my $var = "SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c main.c \  
missing.c msg.c node.c re.c version.c";
```

... Contains a backslash followed by a newline.  The backslash, when used within a string contained in double quotes, functions to escape the immediately following character.  If you do a print of `$var` immediately after this assignment, you'll see that there is, indeed, no backslash in your string.

You have two options to get your regular expression to do what you want it to do.

#### Option 1 - Keep the double-quoted assignment, but remove the backslash from your regular expression.

```
perl -e 'my $var = "SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c main.c \  
missing.c msg.c node.c re.c version.c";  
$var =~ /^\w+=(.*(\n.*))/;  
print "$1\n";'
```

This works.

#### Option 2 - Put your assignment statement in single-quotes, explicitly saying that you **want** a backslash in `$var`:

```
# myfile.pl
my $var = 'SRC=array.c builtin.c eval.c field.c gawkmisc.c io.c main.c \  
missing.c msg.c node.c re.c version.c';  
$var =~ /^\w+=(.*(\\\n.*))/;  
print "$1\n";
```

Because we have single quotes in our code, it's a little simpler not to run this within `perl -e`.

```
> perl myfile.pl
```

This also works.

So, really, the problem does not so much have to do with backtracks and `.*`.  It has to do with your use of the backslash in your string and the result that you expect that usage to have.

Comment: I am not sure how the single quotes make such a difference

Comment: What do you mean by a *"line continuation character"*? The text of a command line is passed through many layers, and it is often difficult to determine the escapes needed to pass on your intention. The OP hasn't said what shell they are using, but even in bash a backslash followed by a newline is special only within *double* quotes. The OP's example string contains precisely a backslash and a linefeed - hex `5C 0A`

Comment: Terming the `'\' '\n'` sequence a “line continuation” is highly misleading (while some languages like sh, python, or the C preprocessor do have such line continuations, Perl isn't one of them). In Perl's double quoted strings, unknown escapes are simply ignored by removing the backslash. This means that `"\ " eq " "`, for example. The same is happening here, just with a different whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

With `(\\\n.*)` you are asking for a *backslash*, followed by a newline, followed by zero or more of any character.

There is no backslash in the string, so your pattern fails to match.

Comment: But in the string I have escaped the new line using `\\` So I am trying to express this escaped new line

Comment: How else could I express it?

Comment: The backslash in your double-quoted string isn't doing anything. If you want to add a literal backslash then you need to escape that backslash by doubling it up. But I think you're making things overly difficult for yourself - where does the *real* data come from, and does it contain backslash characters?